# how to call a function when user reaches the end of horizontal scrollbar in Angular 10?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, scrollbar, horizontal-scrolling

I've certains amounts of item in list within a horizontal scrollbar. I want to load more item via a function when user reaches the end of scrollbar.
I've tried to implement it via (scroll)="onScroll()" but this function won't be called if scollbar can't be scollred further. So, how do I know about the end of an horizontal scollbar?

I've tried it via tracking how much distance, a scrollbar have crossed.

Answer (score 0):

in the `onScroll` function you need to check if the scroll reached the end of most right scroll by

```
if (document.body.scrollWidth - document.body.scrollLeft === document.body.clientWidth) {
  // fetch some data
}
```

I also suggest fetching the data before the scroll reached the bottom with some pixels, to not make the user wait.

For example.

```
if (document.body.scrollWidth - document.body.scrollLeft >= (document.body.clientWidth - 100)) {
  // fetch some data
}
```

Comment: Hey Mina, if it related to horizontal scrollbar, then how will I do that?

Comment: @NitinSaini, I just update the answer, please check again.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suggest you to use an IntersectionObserver in order to see when an item at the bottom of the page has entered the viewport. This is usually a best practice performance wise.

There are many articles out there for using angular directives in order to achieve this and reuse this code (e.g. https://blog.prototyp.digital/how-to-implement-intersection-observer-api-in-angular/), but if you have a quick win, you can just adapt an example from the official IntersectionObserver documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API

You can simply pass a callback function to the IntersectionObserver where you refetch new data.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the reply, sorry but I'm working on a horizontal scrollbar, and I'm not able to detect the end of it.

Comment: Yes, I know. IntersectionObserver will still be the best choice for this use case.